# What is this tunnel with white vertical structures on LC-39A?

Tags: spacex, launchpad

This picture was shown the CRS-10 launch webcast:

[image: LC-39A during SpaceX CRS-10 countdown]
(red frame added by me)

What is the marked tunnel-like opening with the white vertical bars? And what is/was its purpose?

The same structure can also seen in [Google StreetView](https://www.google.com/maps/@28.6071764,-80.6002037,3a,30y,289.02h,92.87t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s55FvUSGk78sJ0h1_5MpNkg!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo1.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D55FvUSGk78sJ0h1_5MpNkg%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D277.31677%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656):
[image: LC-39A in 2012]
This is dated Jan 2012, so this is apparently something from the Apollo or Shuttle era.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the "high pressure gas storage facility". Mostly used for N2.  And yes, it dates from the Apollo era.

[Reference](http://apollolaunchcontrol.com/v20test/http___www.apollolaunchcontrol.com_/Launch_Pads.html) (search the linked page for the word "exploded diagram")

Another [Reference](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=14430.0)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I never realized that there would be such large facilities in there...

Comment: The first linked reference talks about a lot of the inner facilities including the "rubber room".

Answer (score 0):

Those are pressurized gas storage tanks.